# pointer to a two-dimensional matrix in C ++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I am trying to develop a code which relates in part a saved matrix in a file. I use Eclispe luna + Cygwin in  Windows 8.
 And this is my code:

**class A.cpp**

```
        void A::Initialize(string toto){
        string ligne;
        lig = 0; // nbre des lignes
        col=0;
        int copienj[lig];
        ifstream fichier_toto(toto.c_str(), ios::in);

        if(fichier_toto.fail()){
              cout << "Le fichier " << toto << " n'existe pas !" << endl;
        }
        ifstream fichier(toto.c_str(), ios::in);

        if(!fichier.fail())  {
            while(getline(fichier, ligne)){
                lig++;
            }

            int kk=0;
            int llm=ligne.length();
            for(int y=0; y<llm;y++){
                if(ligne[kk]==' '){
                    col++;
                 }
                kk++;
            }
            col++;


            int DLocal[lig-1][col];

            string data1[lig*col];//on stocke les # variables dans un tableau

            fichier.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            if((int)fichier.tellg() != 0) {
                   fichier.clear();
                   fichier.seekg(0, ios::beg);
              }
             for(int i=0; i<(lig*col);i++){
                   fichier >> data1[i] ;  /*on lit jusqu'à l'espace et on stocke ce qui est lu dans la variable indiquée */
             }

             // remplissage de D
             int k=col;
             for(int i=0; i<lig-1;i++){
                for (int j =0; j<col;j++){
                    DLocal[i][j]=atof(data1[k+i+j].c_str());
                }
                k=k+col-1;
            }

            //on cherche D
            D=&DLocal[0][0];
            // nbre delignes dans notre matrice D
            lig--;
            m=col-2;
                /******* on affiche DLocal       *******************/
             cout<<" D From class A"<<endl;
             for(int i=0; i<lig;i++){
                for (int j =0; j<col;j++){
                    cout<<DLocal[i][j]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
    }
```

And **the class B.cpp**

```
B::Function(){
A* dt=new A();
dt->Initialize("E:\\processing_Times_C\\prb3_4.txt");
D=dt->D;
lig=dt->lig;
col=dt->col;
n=dt->n;
m=dt->m;
nb_op=dt->nb_op;
nj=dt->nj;


cout<< "D: "<<endl;
int copie[lig][col];

for(int i=0; i<lig;i++){
    for (int j =0; j<col;j++){
        copie[i][j]=*(D+i*col+j);
    }

}
 cout<<" D From Class B:"<<endl;
 for(int i=0; i<lig;i++){
    for (int j =0; j<col;j++){
        cout<<copie[i][j]<< " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
 }
}
```

Normally I have to get this:

```
D from class A:
1 1 1 3 4 1 
1 2 3 8 2 1 
1 3 3 5 4 7 
2 1 4 1 1 4 
2 2 2 3 9 3 
2 3 9 1 2 2 
3 1 8 6 3 5 
3 2 4 5 8 1 
D from class B:
1 1 1 3 4 1 
1 2 3 8 2 1 
1 3 3 5 4 7 
2 1 4 1 1 4 
2 2 2 3 9 3 
2 3 9 1 2 2 
3 1 8 6 3 5 
3 2 4 5 8 1
```

But I got this :

```
D from class A:
1 1 1 3 4 1 
1 2 3 8 2 1 
1 3 3 5 4 7 
2 1 4 1 1 4 
2 2 2 3 9 3 
2 3 9 1 2 2 
3 1 8 6 3 5 
3 2 4 5 8 1 

D from class B:
 2344128 0 2343792 0 24 0 
 8 0 2344160 0 -16338585 3 
 1 3 3 5 4 7 
 469600 6 469600 6 4 0 
 3 0 -2146642573 1 4 0 
 -16219983 3 9 1 2 2 
 3 1 8 6 2343360 0 
 -2146277029 1 4 5 8 1
```

Do you have an idea to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour. You define a local int array `DLocal`, which will be in the stack. When you return from the function, it will be destroyed. You are storing a pointer to that memory area in `D`, so it can contain whatever data that happens to be in the stack at that point.